# Why didn't Rudy Cooper reveal the true nature of Dexter to Debra in Dexter Season 1?

Tags: character, dexter

So I understand Rudy wanted Dexter to feel the need to connect with him on their mutual urge to killing people in the altercation happening in the final episode of Dexter Season 1. But since Dexter was hesitant towards this, Rudy could have very well threatened Dexter by letting Debra know the true nature of Dexter instead of going one-on-one with him?

Comment: Did he have any prove? I watched it years ago, so I don't remember it very well.

Comment: yup, he knew he was a serial killer

Comment: this question deserves an upvote from all dexter fans, +1 a million times if i could

Comment: I assume it could have been a plot-killer had he revealed it.

Comment: @war_Hero I know that he knew, but could he prove it to Debra in any way? If he didn't have a prove I doubt she would believed him.

Comment: rudy had a photo in which he was standing next to the guards body(who  was presumed to be the ice truck killer) he could have shown that, as dex called deb to inform about the location

Comment: @ChanandlerBong: Rudy wouldn’t need any hard proof. The police already has almost all the evidence they need and can easily acquire the rest. They just need sufficient hints where to look and what pieces to put together.

Comment: I think he thought dex would come along with him and only deb was blocking that from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't have proof to back my theory**, Since Rudy took the time to get to know Dexter more closely, precisely from his childhood days he probably learnt that harry had told him to keep it a secret which he respected.
**OR(the better theory)**
It might also be because **she is a cop** and his little brother might be put on death row if they figured out that he was a serial killer and rudy wanted to spend time with dex not get a means to his end

Comment: Book's spoiler!>                      She wake up and see Dexter talking with Rudy. Dexter refuse to kill Debra and allow Rudy escape

Comment: @RodrigoMenezes didn't know that i should read the book also

Comment: The first season is close to the book, but the end changes everything, then you can read book and watch the series without one spoil the other. The series use some elements from the others books, but the story is different..

Comment: *he probably learnt that harry had told him to keep it a secret which he respected.* – Rudy makes it quite clear that he doesn’t have an ounce of respect for the Code of Harry.

Comment: *It might also be because **she is a cop** and his little brother might be put on death row if they figured out that he was a serial killer* – I think there is a substantial risk of this if Ruby gave anybody sufficient information to unveil Dexter’s true nature.

Answer (score 3):

Rudy’s goal is to make Dexter join him to “reunite the family”. It’s the nature of this endeavour that it only works if Dexter voluntarily embraces this: If Dexter were forced into this by means of threat, there would be nothing keeping him from faking it and backstabbing Rudy on the first occasion. You cannot just force somebody to join the dark side. Also, if forcing were an option for Rudy, there would be no need to go through his elaborate plan to “awaken” Dexter and he could just have threatened him from the very beginning.

Of course, at some point Rudy may have accepted that his plan had failed and thus he would resort to saving his skin, but the earliest point from this is when Dexter prevents him from stabbing Debra and initiates the fight. This fight is so short and intense that there is no real room for making a threat. And this would only makes sense if Rudy noticed that Debra was awake – which is not certain.